# Why does this list element move back in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For context, what I am trying to do is create a top-down display in which the screen is just text which is printed every time the player gives input. What this script does is move the Y upward so that I can find things I could do to move the player when the input is given.

```
minimap=[
        'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH',
        'H                  H',
        'H                  H',
        'H           HHHHHHHH',
        'H                  H',
        'HHHHHHHH           H',
        'H                  H',
        'H          Y       H',
        'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH']
for li in minimap:
    print(li)
count=0
for b in minimap:
    count+=1
    if count==7:
        soi=b
    elif count==8:
        s2i=b
minimap.pop(7)
minimap.pop(6)
list(soi).pop(11)
list(s2i).pop(11)
list(soi).insert(11,' ')
list(s2i).insert(11,'Y')
minimap.insert(7,soi)
minimap.insert(6,s2i)
for li in minimap:
    print(li)
```

So what happens in the two lines

```
minimap.insert(7,soi)
minimap.insert(6,s2i)
```

Is that the new, changed lines are inserted into the `minimap[]` positions of the old lines, which were removed from `minimap[]` (I say this because I believe it is most relevant to the issue).

However this is what happens:

```
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
H                  H
H                  H
H           HHHHHHHH
H                  H
HHHHHHHH           H
H                  H
H          Y       H
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

(New minimap:)

```
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
H                  H
H                  H
H           HHHHHHHH
H                  H
HHHHHHHH           H
H          Y       H
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
H                  H
```

Everything worked as expected, however, (it seems that) line 8 and (new) line 7 swapped positions. Why did this happen?

Comment: Can you think of a way to do this without all the popping and inserting? For example, by replacing values at specific locations? I think you would find it to be much easier and much less code.

Comment: Those `list(...).pop(...)` and `list(...).insert(...)` lines are pointless - you create a brand new list, and perform an operation on that list, but you don't keep the list afterwards.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have tried using replace(), however (at least in the way I used it) what it did was replace (an)other element(s) in that list which had the same value as the element I chose to replace, so if I replaced a character in a string which was a space with a 'Y', that would mean that every space in that string would be turned to a Y.

Comment: No; I said *to replace values*, not to use the .replace method. As in: assign a value to a specific index, that is different from the value it currently has.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry about the misunderstanding. Your suggestion makes sense, I will consider it

Comment: @KarlKnechtel @enzomar You could do things like `minimap[6] = minimap[6][:11] + 'Y' + minimap[6][12:]` Never done python before, so not sure if that's the best way though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is that when you

```
minimap.insert(7,soi)
```

There were only 6 items left in your `minimap`, and the 6th item is `'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH'`.

So by inserting `soi` to the 7th item, you are actually putting it after the `'HHHHHHHHH'`.

Instead, you would want:

```
minimap.insert(6,soi)
minimap.insert(6,s2i)
```

or

```
minimap.insert(6,s2i)
minimap.insert(7,soi)
```